# Get the current order of specific attribute of elements in class as array in jquery-ui sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to get an array of attributes of ordered elements in jquery-ui sortable.

Below is the code I've tried

```
$(".topic_keywords").sortable();

$(".box-item").draggable();    

var keywordOrder = $(".topic_keywords").sortable("toArray", {attribute: 'data-id'});

console.log(keywordOrder);
```

Here are the elements

```
<ul class="topic_keywords" data-id="1">
      <li class="box-item" data-id="1">Item 1</li>
      <li class="box-item" data-id="2">Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul class="topic_keywords" data-id="2">
    <li class="box-item" data-id="3">Item 3</li>
    <li class="box-item" data-id="4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

However, I am only getting the ordered array of first sortable class. How can I get the array from whichever class I am currently sorting the elements of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the order of items that are currently being sorted, I recommend using the [update event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update).

> update( event, ui )
>   This event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.

Here's a demonstration:

```js
$(".topic_keywords").sortable({

  update: function(event, ui) {

    var keywordOrder = $(this).sortable("toArray", {
      attribute: 'data-id'
    });

    console.log(keywordOrder);

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="topic_keywords" data-id="1">
  <li class="box-item" data-id="1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="box-item" data-id="2">Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul class="topic_keywords" data-id="2">
  <li class="box-item" data-id="3">Item 3</li>
  <li class="box-item" data-id="4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: anyway I can access the "keywordOrder" variable outside the sortable declaration?